# Can't import DLL in python. "Unable to find assembly error"

Tags: c#, python, dll, dllimport, python.net

I have few C# programs which I'm trying to convert to python. I don't know anything about C#, I have to import DLL(s) and use the functions used in C# code. I have successfully imported DLL(s) in other codes, but I am unable to import in this particular code.

This is the C# code which I'm trying to refer:

```
namespace Grab
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, int Length);

        private const string SdkFilePath = @".\xyz.dll";


        [DllImport(SdkFilePath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern UInt32 LP_GetLibVersion();
```

What I am doing in Python:

```
import clr
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\DLL\\") #Load DLL file
clr_iow = clr.AddReference("xyz")
```

The C# program works just fine. But when I try to run the python code,
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    clr_iow = clr.AddReference("xyz")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'xyz'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

I have tried changing versions of pythonnet, python. Read Permissions are also given to the DLL file. The other DLL(s) in the same directory get imported. Only this particular one gives this error. Is there another way to import this one? Also I can't find 'kernel.dll', is importing kernel necessary? How do I import that too? 
In other C# programs, DLL(s) where imported simply by doing:

```
using abc;
```

And then in python:

```
import clr
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\DLL\\") #Load DLL file
clr_iow = clr.AddReference("abc")
```

Why can't I do that here? Thanks in advance.